# Advice my first dual-monitor setup

Tags: 22.04, multiple-monitors

I’m thinking to buy a second monitor for my first dual-monitor setup: a BenQ GW2485TC to connect to a Dell XPS13 9370 (Gnome 42.9 – Ubuntu 22.04) via USB-C. The BenQ is a 24” FullHD monitor while the laptop has a 13” FullHD one. Same resolutiones and different sizes (maybe different frequency) could be a problem? On the laptop I use a factor scale of 1.30. Could I use a different factor scale on the second monitor if necessary? Are there other things to know?

Thanks,
Have a good day

Comment: `On the laptop I use a factor scale of 1.30. Could I use a different factor scale on the second monitor if necessary?` KDE supports this with Wayland. Not sure about GNOME